# FTP style double selection dialog bash

Tags: bash, menu, dialog

I need to create a menu to execute under a Linux console. Hence, I thought to use `dialog` in a Bash script.
I do not just understand if (and how) it is possible to achieve the following:

```
+--------+              +--------+
|object 1|              |selectd1| 
|object 2|    >>>>      |selectd2|
|object 3|              |  ...   |
|object 4|    <<<<      |        |
|  ...   |              |        |
+--------+              +--------+
```

a double box menu to choose elements from a comprehensive list and put them in a new list (**order matters**).
Am I on the right way ?

EDIT:
given a default configuration file, I want to activate certain elements and write a new custom configuration file. The order of activation will affect my program.
So far, I created the following:

```
object 1  ... [-]
object 2  ... [3]
object 3  ... [1] 
object 4  ... [2]
```

but the user has to mark the chosen element giving its order number (a bit cumbersome).

Comment: Please can you explain more about what are you doing. Paste some more info and code.

Comment: I edited the question. I hope it is more understandable now.

Answer (score 2):

You can't have two active widgets at the same time using `dialog`. However if you find a way to automaticly close widget (without user interaction) you can use `--keep-window` and update state of the second (inactive) widget.